# Sorting Database list android by likes

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building recipes app. I have page in my app that retrieves all the recipes from the database on Firebase into ListView. Each Recipe has these variables:

```
public String key;
public String uid;
public String title;
public String type;
public String ingredients;
public String instructions;
public int likes;
```

Here's the function that retrieves all the data :

```
//Retrieve Data from database
public void retriveData() {
    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Recipe r = data.getValue(Recipe.class);
                recipes.add(r);
            }
            allRecipeAdapter = new AllRecipeAdapter(AllRecipeActivity.this,0,0,recipes);
            lv.setAdapter(allRecipeAdapter);
        }
     }
 }
```

Now i want to create another screen that also has a ListView and i would like to sort the Recipes by nubmer of likes and then enter the top 10 recipes into the ListView.
I searched on Google i found the function OrderByValue but i can't figure out how to use it i realized how to works but i can't implement this to my project.

Comment: Show what you've already tried with OrderByValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaëtan Maisse and KLHauser gave you solutions that work in pure client-side code. Here's an alternative that uses Firebase Database queries, which means the ordering *and filtering* happen on the server:

```
// assuming that database refers to the list of all recipe
Query topRecipes = database.orderByChild("likes").limitToLast(10);
topRecipes.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        recipes = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
        for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Recipe r = data.getValue(Recipe.class);
            // add the recipe to the front of the list
            recipes.add(0, r);
        }
        allRecipeAdapter = new AllRecipeAdapter(AllRecipeActivity.this,0,0,recipes);
        lv.setAdapter(allRecipeAdapter);
    }
 }
```

Since Firebase queries always sort items in ascending order, the query takes the *last* 10 items - those are the ones with the highest like count. To reverse those items, the code *inserts* each item to the from of the list, instead of appending them to the end.

Comment: Where i need to put this code? In the onCreate()  function ?

Comment: It's the same code you had before, but modified to use a query. So you'd put it wherever you had the code previously. If you're having trouble determining where to wire up the database listeners, share the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is the first one that i used on the regular non-sorted ListView :

Comment: The first function that i used was the one in my post it was the non_sorted list i wrote it as a function after the onCreate() function. but this function that you gave me i just pasted it in the onCreate() function. You're saying that i need to put it wherever i previously wrote the last one. So should i create second function and call it for Example "retrieveSortedData" and than paste into that function the code that you gave me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your list using a `Comparator` and then get a sublist of 10 first elements before displaying it in the `ListView`:

```
Comparator<Recipe> likesOrderComparator = new Comparator<Recipe>() { 
    public int compare(Recipe recipe1, Recipe recipe2) {
        return recipe1.likes < recipe2.likes ? -1 : recipe1.likes == recipe2.likes ? 0 : 1;
    }
}; 

Collections.sort(recipes, likesOrderComparator);

List<Recipe> topTenRecipes = recipes.subList(0, 9);

// Now display topTenRecipes in a ListView
```

Answer (score 1):

Java7:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Recipe>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Recipe r1, Recipe r2) {
        if (r1.getLikes() > r2.getLikes())
            return 1;
        if (r1.getLikes() < r2.getLikes()
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Java8 (using lambda):

```
recipes.stream()
    .sorted((r1, r2) -> Integer.compare(r1.getLikes(),
                    r2.getLikes()))
```